# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Products#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to link each image from my index page (products_path) to my show page.

In my controller I currently have:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_product, only: [:show]

  def index
    @products = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/*.jpg")
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def find_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And in my index view page:

```
<% Dir[File.join("public/assets", "*.jpg")].each do |file| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag file.gsub('public', ''), product_path(@product), class: 'img-responsive col-lg-3' %>
<% end %>
```

This results in an error which I've been trying to fix for quite a while. I hope anyone has some experience with this error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I thought 'products' was empty but when I check the console, there are a few Product attributes with images in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
@products = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/*.jpg")
```

What is this?

Why are you filling an instance variable with the glob of all the images in your `assets/images` directory? You can call that in your view.

You shouldn't have this in the controller; you shouldn't even have it because it's a bad pattern (not object orientated).

--

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

This error is caused by you're calling a `link_to` without an appropriate `id` to send into the request. <s>I appreciate you're sending `@product`; it's either that this has not been invoked properly, or you're calling it incorrectly.</s>

The problem here is that you're passing `@product` without actually setting it... `before_action :find_product, only: [:show]` - the `index` action won't have `@product` available.

This problem would be fixed with my recommendation below. Or simply, you have to populate the `link_to` with either an `id` value, or an object.

---

## Fix

You should be attaching your images to your `Product` model.

You can use [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [`Carrierwave`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to do this:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :image #-> paperclip implementation
end
```

This will allow you to upload images for the model itself (I can write more about this if required).

You'd then be able to use the OOP pattern:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

end
```

Then in your view:

```
#app/views/products/index.html.erb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.name %>
   <%= image_tag product.image.url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have added the Paperclip gem to my gemfile. And adjusted the code from your suggestions. The only strange thing is, the way Paperclip renders the images in the view. As an example: `/system/products/images/000/000/001/original/app/assets/images/Cup-1.jpg`. So it doesn't show me the images on the index view but instead, renders the names of all available Products.

Comment: I don't understand, if you have `image_tag`, it will attempt to render an image, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought. Maybe it's the way how the Product.rb saves the images. I'm using Rufus-scheduler to scan a folder each time i run my server. If it finds new images it writes it to the Product model. The code i'm using `require 'rufus-scheduler'
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler::singleton
scheduler.in '5s' do
  Product.new
  @products = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/*.jpg")
  @products.each do |product|
    Product.find_or_create_by(image_file_name: product)
  end
end` With this i get the image in my Product.rb as `image_file_name: "app/assets/images/reni_blokzijl-4.jpg"`

Comment: So do you have the images in your `public/system` directory?

Comment: Yes, I precompile them afterwards.

Comment: Are the images in your `products` datatable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99801/discussion-between-testbuck-and-rich-peck).